# Object Oriented Programming, not getting filtered by the if and else// and

Tags: oop, if-statement

So currently studying OOP, I have encountered a problem regarding why the numbers are not getting filtered by my range in the if and else statements, and also one more thing on the last part of the code there should be something with the lines of "public String showDetails()" but I don't know what is inside of it.

```
    package com.xble.department.domain

public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int EmpNo;
    private int age;
    
    public Person()
    {
        
    }
    public Person(String n, int en, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        
        if((en < 0) && (en >= 1) && (en <= 999999))
            en = 0;
        else 
            EmpNo = en;
        
        if((a < 0) && (a >= 1) && (a <= 65))
            a = 0;
        else 
            age = a;
    }   
    
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name=n;
    }
    
    public void setEmpNo(int en)
    {
            if((en < 0) && (en >= 1) && (en <= 999999))
                en = 0;
            else 
                EmpNo = en;
    }

    public void setAge(int a)
    {
            if((a < 0) && (a >= 1) && (a <= 65))
                a = 0;
            else 
                age = a;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getEmpNo()
    {
        return EmpNo;
    }
    
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    
    //public String showDetails()
    
}
```

Comment: `(en < 0) && (en >= 1)` can never be true.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, I will take note of this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```java
(en < 0) && (en >= 1)
```

This can never be true. For any given int value of `en`, it can not be below 0 *and* above or equal 1. This same condition is repeated in all the `if` statements.

Regarding the `showDtails()` method it looks like there should be some logic that returns a string, presumably with the details of this Person.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, `if((en >= 1) && (en <= 999999))` I think this does the trick.

I have compiled it and it showed the results that I desired.

Is it possible for me to do `return "Name: " + name + "\nEmpNo: "` so on and so forth

Comment: @HumbleNewb13 Yes, you can totally do that, and you can maybe make it a bit cleaner if you write it like `public String showDetails() => $"Name: {name}\nEmpNo: {EmpNo};`, depending on how big your return string is.

Comment: I will take note of this response and use it likewise on my current code. Thank you.